# Erro na consulta Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Ola! surgiu essa duvida na consulta mysql;

porque o status esta vindo diferente da tabela?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

segue minha consulta:

```
SELECT DISTINCT max(idEmbreagem) as idEmbreagem, b.prefixo as idVeiculo, max(datamontagem) as datamontagem, max(kmmontagem) as kmmontagem, max(horimetromontagem) as horimetromontagem, max(c.km) as kmatual, max(c.horimetro) as horimetroatual, a.`status`, max(tipoembreagem) as tipoembreagem, (max(c.km) - max(a.kmmontagem)) as kmrodados FROM embreagem a
              JOIN veiculos b on (a.idVeiculo=b.idVeiculo)
              JOIN hodometro c on (a.idVeiculo=c.idVeiculo)
              GROUP BY a.idVeiculo order by idVeiculo ASC
```

Comment: Pra q esse monte de `MAX()`?

Comment: ultimo dados de cada veiculo

Answer (score 2):

Amigo, ditinct com max... Alguma coisa me parece muito mal aí... =/

O fato é que o distinct e os MAX()'s estão bagunçando os resultados, embaralhando eles... Você deveria pensar melhor para montar essa query.

Answer (score 1):

Devido você estar trazendo vários max na query, ele ta embaralhando os resultados com max de cada select seguindo as condicionais.

Answer (score 0):

Se você quer pegar os dados mais recentes das tabelas `embreagem` e `hodometro`, faça assim:

```
SELECT b.idembreagem, a.prefixo idveiculo, a.datamontagem,
       a.kmmontagem, a.horimetromontagem, c.km kmatual,
       c.horimetro horimetroatual, b.status, b.tipoembreagem,
       (c.km - a.kmmontagem) as kmrodados
FROM veiculos a
JOIN embreagem b ON b.idveiculo = a.idveiculo
JOIN hodometro c ON c.idveiculo = a.idveiculo
WHERE b.idembreagem IN (SELECT MAX(idembreagem) FROM embreagem GROUP BY idveiculo)
AND c.idhodometro IN (SELECT MAX(idhodometro) FROM hodometro GROUP BY idveiculo)
ORDER BY a.prefixo ASC
```